# Security in web services consumed in flex

Tags: security

What would be the best way to secure .net web services used by a flex application.

1. The Flex application is not public website and has no login
2. I don't want to anybody to browse my web services directly in browser like "www.mywebservice.com/services.asmx"
3. The webservices should be only accessed by my Flex application and It will be good If I allow some developer machines to access it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Flex applications is loaded in a browser and uses the browser for sending http requests to the server.

The easiest way to secure the connection to the server would be to serve the flex application and the web service on ssl. That is, simply turn on ssl on the web server where your flex application and your web services is hosted. This would give you encryption of all communication between your flex application and the server.

To get access control you will need to require the end user to use a client ssl certificate as well. To do this, you will have to configure your server to require client side ssl. certificates and issue client certificates that each user will have to install in their browser.

This may not be what you wanted. Maybe you don't want the end user to log in, but you still only want your flex application to access the web services. But that would be impossible to achieve in a secure way. If your flex application should be able to access the web service then the flex application will have to have some kind of access credentials (i.e. a password or a certificate). This would have to be stored inside the flex application or be accessible from the flex application in some way. Since the flex application is downloaded to your browser, then all users would have access to the entire content of the application. If the password or certificate is stored inside the application, then anyone that can download the application would find it there.